# Objective C - Bundle file (Facebook)

Tags: objective-c

I'm looking at the sample code for Facebook Connect (http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and noticed that it is using a FBConnect.bundle file that contains some images.

I have never used a bundle file and am just curious as how to create / edit it.
Is it done through XCode?

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simple [document package](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/DocumentPackages/DocumentPackages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH106-SW1) and here basically consists of nothing more than naming the directory with a `.bundle` suffix.
[`FBLoginButton.m`](http://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/sample/DemoApp/Classes/FBLoginButton.m) shows that its used similarly trivially:

```
// ...
return [UIImage imageNamed:@"FBConnect.bundle/images/logout.png"];
```

Comment: Didn't know it's just making a directory with .bundle extension. Was trying "New project" > bundle etc. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be see [Apple's conception docs on Bundles](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i)