# Pros of storing image resources inside a .bundle

Tags: xcode, ios, resources, organization

I've been told that it's best practice to do so. I know the [Facebook iOS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) does this (look inside the `FBDialog.bundle` file). There are a few SO questions about [how to create them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672670) as well. Apple also has a [Bundle Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH1-SW1).

But in a nutshell (and localization aside), are there significant pros of storing image resources inside a .bundle file?

**EDIT**: I know that the .app product is a bundle itself. That is not my question. The question is whether to store the image resources inside the default "Resources" group or to store them inside a "Resource.bundle" file, like the Facebook iOS SDK does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just adds another layer of organization to your application bundle, making it more comprehensive. The only strict advantage I could see for using bundles in this manner would be to avoid potential file conflicts when using lots of 3rd party code in a same project.

Answer (score 0):

Bundles provide a standardized structure for organizing resources. On iOS it's not like you have a wide range of options with respect to where you store resources.

Comment: So are you saying bundles are kind of overkill on iOS?

Comment: I think the point is that on iOS, you don't have much choice other than to store your images in your app's bundle.

Comment: You have a small degree of choice where in the bundle you place resource in iOS, but it's best to follow conventions to make your life easier.